# How to gain administrator privileges on a kid's Android 6 phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-play-services, device-administrator, parental-control

I have an old functional Honor phone with Android 6 which would be perfect for the little ones to use basic apps such as Spotify Kids or Youtube Kids.

I created a Google kids account, added it to my family and got myself a Family link app for parents where I can control the kid's account.

Then, I have factory-reset the Honor and set it up with the kid's account.

But now I am locked out. I cannot seem to find a way get parent's administrator rights. When I go to Settings > Security > Administrators I can only see an active parents administrator but the setting is grayed out. I cannot access it.

Also, I cannot find any button or app that contains the entry to "parent access."

What can I do?

To add more complexity: I cannot install any apps because the Google Play Services are too old and you cannot update the services without updating them first ;)

As administrator I would be able to manually upgrade the services so that I can restore Play functionally completely (I have done this before). But now with the kid's account I can no longer install apps from untrusted sources (fortunately), but it seems I can also no longer gain parent access.

How to gain administrator privileges on a kid's Android 6 phone? Does anyone remember? Otherwise I might have soft-bricked the device and locked myself out forever.

Comment: factory reset again?

Comment: I cannot factory reset it without admin privileges.

Comment: you cannot enter recovery mode?